# AWS ECS: Not able to access via URL. Giving You don't have permission to access this resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, drupal, amazon-ecs

[Dockerizing Drupal 8 on AWS ECS Error: Task failed ELB health checks in Target group for Drupal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60304117/dockerizing-drupal-8-on-aws-ecs-error-task-failed-elb-health-checks-in-target-g)

Above thing is working fine now. Seems missing Apache or PHP configuration, so not able to access the website.

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.

Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) Server at 51.11.211.110 Port 80
```

`DockerFile`

```
FROM drupal:8.6-apache

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    curl \
    git \
    mysql-client \
    vim \
    wget

RUN php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');" && \
    php composer-setup.php && \
    mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer && \
    php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"

RUN wget -O drush.phar https://github.com/drush-ops/drush-launcher/releases/download/0.4.2/drush.phar && \
    chmod +x drush.phar && \
    mv drush.phar /usr/local/bin/drush

COPY apache-drupal.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

WORKDIR /drupal/web
```

`docker-compose.yml` file

```
version: '3'
services:
  drupal:
    image: drupal:latest
    container_name: drupal
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
    volumes:
      - ./:/drupal/web
    restart: always
```

`apache-drupal.conf` file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/drupal/web/"
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    <Directory "/drupal/web/">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /drupal/web/error.log
    CustomLog /drupal/web/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

It gives above error. May be something I am missing in `DockerFile`?

Error in docker log

> Cannot serve directory /var/www/web/: No matching DirectoryIndex
>   (index.php,index.html) found, and server-generated directory index
>   forbidden by Options directive

**[UPDATE]**

After adding `apache.conf` file it is giving below error

> AH00014: Configuration check failed No such file or directory:
>   AH02291: Cannot access directory '/var/www/web/docker/logs/' for error
>   log of vhost defined at /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1

Now I am able to access via IP, but it is only showing `error.log` & `access.log` file. Not my Drupal project

Comment: this is an apache error, check apache conf ....

Comment: I am not sure how to check this one

Comment: docker logs or apache logs in docker

Comment: Hi @LinPy I have updated question will all the information. Please have a look in to that

Comment: do you have `index.php,index.html` in ` /var/www/web/` ? and do you have `DirectoryIndex index.html index.php` in apache.conf ?

Comment: Hi @LinPy Please check the update in question. I have added apache.conf file now getting above errors

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208168/discussion-between-ankit-shah-and-linpy).